# How to give bitnami user edit permission on .htaccess for bitnami multisite ec2?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, bitnami, multisite

I have installed a Bitnami Multisite Wordpress AMI on my Amazon EC2 instance. to setup the Multiite Network I need to make changes in the .htaccess file.

I checked the permission on the file :
**-rw-r--r--  1 daemon  daemon   235 Nov 29 12:15 .htaccess**

I need the **bitnami** user to be able to edit the file. So first I did

**getfacl .htaccess**

```
# file: .htaccess
# owner: daemon
# group: daemon
user::rw-
group::r--
other::r--
```

I am logged in as **bitnami** user. So i used the command as below to give **bitnami** edit permissions.

**sudo setfacl –m u:bitnami:rwx .htaccess**

But I get the error as

```
Usage: setfacl [-bkndRLP] { -m|-M|-x|-X ... } file ...
Try `setfacl --help' for more information.
```

Need help to resolve the same.

Thanks

Comment: Got this to work. Seems like a typo with the - minus sign before m.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here.

You can change the permissions of the .htaccess file by running this command

```
sudo chown bitnami:daemon .htaccess
sudo chmod g+w .htaccess
```

After running those commands, you can start to edit the file.

For security and performance reasons, we do not allow Apache to read the .htaccess files. For this reason, we moved the configuration in the .htaccess files to the main application configuration files and set the AllowOverride option to None by default.

You have two different options to start using .htaccess files:
- Edit the `/opt/bitnami/apps/mediawiki/conf/htaccess.conf` file and include the information of the .htaccess file inside a Directory block. You will find more information about this in this guide

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress-multisite/administration/use-htaccess/

- Edit the `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-app.conf` file and change the AllowOverride option to All. After that, you will need to restart Apache

In both options, you will need to restart Apache after that:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions and will have a better read and consider the same accordingly. That aside my query stands as to why the setfacl is failing. And thoughts for the same? Thanks